# login issue with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I recently install SQL server 2014 in my PC and I selected SQL authentication rather than Windows authentication after completion of installation when I tried to log in my server it shows this error even my server name and password was correct even though it shows this what to do now!!
following is the error message shows when I try to log in.....

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to AADI_SQLSERVER.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

The network path was not found

---

---

Comment: Sounds like your username and passwiord is not correct. Have a look at [Disaster Recovery: How to regain your lost sysadmin access](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Security/87159/)

Comment: at the time of installation, it asked to set my password when I selected to set SQL authentication so now what is my default username?

Comment: Most likely it'll be `sa`.

Comment: I also try "sa" that is also not working

Comment: Then, most likely, the password you're entering is incorrect. You'll need to follow the instructions in the link I provided a couple of weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states "network-related or instance-specific error" its related not being able to find the instance.

This maybe due wrong instance name, Check the spellings of the server that you are connecting to.

You may have installed a named instance like sqlexpress in that case the server name should be {YourServer}\Sqlexpress.

You can get your instance name by going to services, if its MSSQLSERVER you can connect with the machine name else you should provide the correct instance name.
Please refer the screenshot below.
[image: Services]

If you are connecting to another machine check the network configuration of the instance by going to sql server configuration manager. If the status is disabled you can connect from outside.

[image: Sql server configuration manager]

If that also fails better check the firewall settings